# Read extern file and wait for changes in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I want to read a file and when the file changed (i.e. for a external program), print the new information readed.
Something like this:

```
import sys, os

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    fid = f.fileno()
    r = os.fdopen(fid)
    while True:
        print r.read()
```

And when I do:

```
echo "Hello world!" > file.txt
```

The python script show:

```
> Hello world!
```

Many thanks.

---

EDITED:
The solution:

```
time = os.path.getmtime('file.txt')
while True:
    if (time <> os.path.getmtime('file.txt')):
        with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
            info = f.read()
            print "Readed: " + info
        time = os.path.getmtime('file.txt')
```

Comment: Look at this https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get file modified time, read if it increases from the old time.

```
import os
import time
fileName = 'test'
originalTime = os.path.getmtime(fileName)

while(True):
    if(os.path.getmtime(fileName) > originalTime):
        with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
            print "\n" + f.read(),
        originalTime = os.path.getmtime(fileName)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Only works if the edit is appended on the old file.

Comment: A file could change without changing its size.

Comment: os.path.getmtime(file) get the file edited time with this, same principle without seeking to the originalsize

Comment: With os.path.getmtime works for me. It isn't very elegant, but works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check Python watchdog. [Python Watchdog quickstart](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html)

watchdog.events.FileModifiedEvent should do the trick.